# Gradle list dependencies without omit

Tags: gradle

I would like to get the dependencies for an project without omitting dependency that have been listed before in the dependency tree.

This is an example of an omitted dependency:

```
org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.1.RELEASE (*)
(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

I have looked at [DependencyReportTask](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/diagnostics/DependencyReportTask.html) without finding any info.

I temporarily solved this by doing the following:

https://github.com/ki82/gradle/commit/d0ac3f6a523759a037a7848c8b8695c3ad15a7d6

Although I would still like to be able to change this by configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for isn't currently possible. You are welcome to submit this as an "idea" over at http://forums.gradle.org (please explain your motivation).